# Regular Expression: find last n number

Tags: regex

I need your help in finding last 6 digits with Regular Expression.

Example, suppose I have below string as input string (including white spaces at the end):

```
1510261026DR000000000198,00NCHK00294541
```

Output: `294541`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: why not slice it after stripping whitespace from the end? In python it would simply be `s.rstrip()[-6:]`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility with perl style regex would be:

```
/(\d{6})\s*$/
```

For example:

```
my $v="1510261026DR000000000198,00NCHK00294541        ";
$v =~ /(\d{6})\s*$/;
printf "$1\n";
```

produces

```
294541
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be: `/([0-9]{6})\s$/`